# QtableView extract data without selection

Tags: qt, qtableview

I am using a qtableview and i would like to extract all the visible column
I cannot use the model because some columns are hidden
and I do not have a selection.
Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can test if column is hidden: `QTableView::isColumnHidden(int column)`